# what does it mean to trace the infix evaluation algorithm?

Tags: java

I have this question that states

```
Given:  5 + 3 * ( 6 - 2 / 3 ) + 4
```

- Trace the infix evaluation algorithm.
- What is the equivalent postfix expression?
- Very briefly explain the process you followed in the trace

I want to understand what they mean by "trace"

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Trace" just means write out step by step how the algorithm solves the expression.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software).  But note that in your case you are not being asked to implement logging.  You are being asked to do *by hand* what trace logging would do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really a question about understanding IT terminology rather than programming.